# C# windows form, how to hide the panel and show after button click?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a panel that contains a lot of textboxes and labels. I want to hide it before i enter password, after button click, that panel need to be shown. So when I try to run the program, it has null reference exception. I'm new at windows form coding.

public form1()
{

```
 panel.Visible=false;
```

}

Comment: Do search for a tutorial! This place is for folks who have at least enough knowledge to a) run into real coding problems and b) read the help pages.

Answer (score 0):

In form load event write this

panel1.Visible = false;

And in button click event :

```
panel1.Visible = true;
```

problem solved

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you call this line after the InitializeComponent() method call in the constructor :-)

Eg:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To make an uielement visible:

```
panel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
```

To make an uielement hidden

```
panel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapse
```

Comment: jei shuorer bacca minus dey or ma ke chudi